# Background screws up on .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

http://www.heuvel-folie-serres.com/Veestal_v2/?pagina=foliestallen_projecten

There are links on this page saying *Foto's...* which trigger a div being shown using jQuery (.show()). This works perfectly on Google Chrome, but on IE something strange happens (even stranger than usual I mean). When someone clicks the link, the div shows... and the background suddenly... well.... let's just say it screws up. In the top left corner it's still a bit visible, but on the rest of the page it has seamingly dissappeared... I don't really know how to describe this problem, neither do I have a clue how to solve it.
By background I mean the transparent overlay where the whole website is on (div#website).

Any brilliant ideas?

Comment: I just tested it out with IE (IE8) and it works fine.

Comment: What the heck?! xD
I tested it on 3 computers and they all have this problem, and they still do...

Comment: All I can say is, that Internet Explorer (at least beyond 8) has a huge problem with little transparent gif's and/or png's. You have a 1px * 1px transparent png there. Try resizing it to 10px * 10px or even 25px * 25px (seems to perform better)

Comment: @GNi33 If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it. It worked xD

Comment: @RobinJ okay, done. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is, that Internet Explorer (at least beyond 8) has a huge problem with little transparent gif's and/or png's. You have a 1px * 1px transparent png there. Try resizing it to 10px * 10px or even 25px * 25px (seems to perform better)